# Cannot pull SQS message from my EC2 instance

Tags: php, symfony, aws-sdk, amazon-sqs

When I deploy my application to a EC2 instance, it fails to fetch messages from my SQS queue. And instead throws an exception with the status code `403 Forbidden, access to the resource {sqs queue} is denied`. However, when I run the same code from my local environment my application can fetch messages from the SQS queue.

My application uses the symfony framework and passes pre-configured AWS credentials, for a user who has access to this queue, from the parameters.yml into `\Aws\Sqs\SqsClient()`.

If on the EC2 instance I run aws configure and configure the aws cli with the same credentials the application can pull messages from the SQS queue. I am concerned here because it is like the aws sdk is overriding the credentials I pass it.

As a example the following code even with hard coded parameters which I have checked are valid credentials, returns a 403 when ran on a EC2 instances.

```
 $sqs = new \Aws\Sqs\SqsClient([
        [
            'key' => '{my key}',
            'secret' => '{my secret}'
        ],
        'region' => 'us-east-1',
        'version' => 'latest'
    ]);

    $response = $sqs->receiveMessage([
        'QueueUrl' => 'https://sqs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/{my account}/{my queue}'
    ]);
```

Does anyone have any suggestions about what may be happening here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `credentials` key in config.

```
$sqs = new \Aws\Sqs\SqsClient([
    'credentials' => [
            'key'    => '{my key}',
            'secret' => '{my secret}',
        ],
        'region' => 'us-east-1',
        'version' => 'latest'
    ]);

    $response = $sqs->receiveMessage([
        'QueueUrl' => 'https://sqs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/{my accoun}/{my queue}'
    ]);
```

Comment: Thank, I should have spotted that, lol. At least I know know now that the sdk is working as expected, it must fallback on to ~/.aws/credentials if it get a 403. So the problem i'm having must be an application level issue.

Answer (score 1):

This might help you to debug your issue.

1. Run `aws sqs list-queues` on command line. If your queue not listed in the result set, that means your AWS key doesn't have permission.
2. Run `aws sqs receive-message --queue-url <queue_url>` where queue_url is your queue's complete url received from step 1. You should see all your messages in the queue.

If there are no errors in above both steps, there might be an issue in your application end.

Comment: Both these commands return a "Access Denied" but this is expected because the instances profile does not have access to these queues. Only the user I have configured in my application and passed into \Aws\Sqs\SqsClient() has access to the queues. I have even tried hard coding the values to check if its an issue with symfony's dependency injection container. Be even when hard coded with valid credentials the SQSClient still returns a 403 on the EC2 instances, yet locally its fine.

Comment: I would suggest to create a aws cli profile with that credentials. For that u will have to edit ~/.aws/credentials file. Please refer the documentation below:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-multiple-profiles.html

Once the profile added, you may use above commands with --profile <profile_name>

Comment: Has the same iam user credentials work fine in your local ?

Comment: Can you paste your configurations you use in SQSClient (without actual key/secret) ? I hope you use correct region ?

Comment: Yes, please see above ^ I have added a example to my post.

Comment: Can you try as below:


$sqs = new \Aws\Sqs\SqsClient([
 'credentials' => [
         'key'    => '{my key}',
         'secret' => '{my secret}',
     ],
        'region' => 'us-east-1',
        'version' => 'latest'
    ]);

    $response = $sqs->receiveMessage([
        'QueueUrl' => 'https://sqs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/{my accoun}/{my queue}'
    ]);

Using `credentials` key.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bad practice to store AWS credentials in EC2 instances, It's much  better to create an IAM role with `sqs:receiveMessage` permission then attach that IAM role to your EC2 instance.